# Track bitmap memory allocation

Tags: android, bitmap

I am developing a game which uses a lot of bitmap allocations. I am also recycling the bitmaps by himself. I want to track memory which is allocated to bitmaps. Is there any way to track them in Android? Here is example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Log.i("MainActivity", "" + Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize());
    Bitmap bitmap = loadBitmap(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bg1), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    Log.i("MainActivity", "" + Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize());
    bitmap.recycle();
    bitmap = null;
    System.gc();
    Log.i("MainActivity", "" + Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize());  

}

public static Bitmap loadBitmap(Drawable drawable, Config bitmapConfig) {
    int width = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
    int height = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
    Bitmap mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, bitmapConfig);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    return mBitmap;

  }
}
```

Comment: what do u mean by track ?? What actions would u intent take based on that ?

Comment: I want to see that if i am using bitmaps, how space will be consumed by bitmaps? If I recycle them and call garbage collector, the memory should free which are consumed by them.

Comment: probably then u should check the heap in DDMS. That would give u a fair idea about that

Comment: The memory which is allocated to bitmaps is native heap which is not garbage collected. The heap in DDMS is same or different? Another question is that why our native heap size is increased every time we run the application? I logged the size with Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize().